# Performance of matching substrings that do not contain bar

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

In Perl, which of the following regex constructs would be the fastest?

1. `/foo(?>.*?bar)/s`
2. `/foo(?:(?!bar).)*+bar/s`
3. `/foo(?:[^b]++|b(?!ar))*+bar/`

For large strings with large distance between `foo` and `bar` (with moderate `b` content). (PCRE answers would also be interesting.)

Comment: No answer can be complete without the input data.  A regexp that performs comparatively well against one string may not do so well against another.  Also, older versions of Perl didn't do as good a job with alternation as newer versions, so the answer will also be somewhat version dependent.

Comment: Perl 5.12 or newer. Whatever input data and version you might have an answer for, it would be valuable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `ab(?>.*?cd)`
2. `ab(?:(?!cd).)*+cd`
3. `ab(?:[^c]++|c(?!d))*+cd`

In the simple case as in the question above, with a long test string, and the following code on Perl 5.12, the answer is that the **first regex beats the others** by far, the second one being the slowest (as suspected).

These were the results in iterations per second (scaled to the slowest one):

1. **23.49** x iter/sec
2. **1.00** x iter/sec
3. **3.35** x iter/sec

---

Using the code:

```
use v5.12;
use Benchmark qw(:hireswallclock :all);

my $str = '';
my $ab = 'ab' x 1024**2;
$str .= $ab . 'cd';
$str .= $ab . 'cde';
$str .= $ab . 'cdef';
$str .= $ab . 'cdefg';
$str .= $ab . 'cdefgh';

printf "Test string length: %.2f MiB\n", (length($str)/1024**2);

timethese(-10, {
    '0:index'       => sub { index($str, 'cdefgh') },

    '1:match'       => sub { $str =~ /ab(?>.*?cdefgh)/ },
    '1:fail'        => sub { $str =~ /ab(?>.*?cdefgg)/ },

    '2:match'       => sub { $str =~ /ab(?:(?!cdefgh).)*+cdefgh/ },
    '2:fail'        => sub { $str =~ /ab(?:(?!cdefgg).)*+cdefgg/ },

    '3:match'       => sub { $str =~ /ab(?:[^c]++|c(?!defgh))*+cdefgh/ },
    '3:fail'        => sub { $str =~ /ab(?:[^c]++|c(?!defgg))*+cdefgg/ },
});
```

Output:

```
Test string length: 10.00 MiB
Benchmark: running 0:index, 1:fail, 1:match, 2:fail, 2:match, 3:fail, 3:match for at least 10 CPU seconds...
   0:index: 11.0578 wallclock secs (10.00 usr +  0.00 sys = 10.00 CPU) @ 246.70/s (n=2467)
    1:fail: 11.0379 wallclock secs (10.05 usr +  0.00 sys = 10.05 CPU) @ 245.05/s (n=2462)
   1:match: 11.9981 wallclock secs (10.08 usr +  0.00 sys = 10.08 CPU) @ 63.80/s (n=643)
    2:fail: 12.0531 wallclock secs (10.53 usr +  0.00 sys = 10.53 CPU) @ 255.25/s (n=2688)
   2:match: 11.0573 wallclock secs (10.13 usr +  0.00 sys = 10.13 CPU) @  2.67/s (n=27)
    3:fail: 12.8325 wallclock secs (10.78 usr +  0.00 sys = 10.78 CPU) @ 266.58/s (n=2874)
   3:match: 11.8457 wallclock secs (10.09 usr +  0.00 sys = 10.09 CPU) @  9.31/s (n=94)
```

Failing is fast in these cases. That seems to be due to that Perl probably does a scan for all plain submatch strings first, and fails if those are not found (same speed as `index`).

Answer (score 5):

```
use Benchmark;
```

to find out exact measurements.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is easy enough to test, I assume you're asking either as a brain teaser or as a way of checking your own assumptions; I'll bite. ;)

I'd expect #3 to be fastest.  `.*?bar` is effectively the same as `(?:(?!bar).)*`, so #1 and #2 both have to do a lookahead at every position.  #3 only does one whenever it sees a `b`.